# Python requests and urllib2 get different headers when connecting to the same host

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

We've got a server providing .txt files, basically some log files growing over time. When I use `urllib2` to send `GET` to the server `r = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com')` , the headers of the response would be:

```
Date: XXX
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: XXX
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12345678
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

While if `r = requests.get('http://example.com')`:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-alive: timeout=5, max=128
Last-Modified: XXX
Connection: Keep-Alive
ETag: xxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The second response is the same with what I get using chrome develop tools. So why the two are different? I need the `Content-Length` header to determine how many bytes I need to download every time, becasue the file could grow really big.

EDIT:
Using `httpbin.org/get` to test:

urllib2 response:

```
{u'args': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept-Encoding': u'identity',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'Python-urllib/2.7'},
 u'origin': u'ip',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get'}
```

response headers:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 14 Jan 2017 07:41:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 207
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

requests response:

```
{u'args': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.11.1'},
 u'origin': u'ip',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get'}
```

response headers:

```
Server : nginx
Date : Sat, 14 Jan 2017 07:42:39 GMT
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Length : 239
Connection : keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
```

Comment: Are are _sending_ the same headers in each case?

Comment: Are you sure the service you're reaching are intact? Since it's a corporate service, maybe someone did a mistake and there are few different webserver under the same virtual ip? If you try to refresh (CTRL+F5) in chrome, do you consistently getting the same response?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hi, yes, the server requires basic auth. In urllib2 I manually add 'Authorization': 'Basic XXX', while in requests I use requests.get('url', auth=('user', 'password')). All other settings are default.

Comment: @iTayb In chrom I get 200 or 304 not modified from time to time. If the log file doesn't change, status code 304 should be right? Newbie about http here, but the server side is out of my control :)

Comment: Try sending your requests to `http://httpbin.org/get` and check the responses to see if both send the same headers; then adjust to make the headers for both exactly the same and see if the server response is different.

Comment: Two more things you might try, otherwise I don't know:  (1) send a 'Connection: close' header with the `requests` request and see if this forces the server to provide content-length in the response; (2) send a HEAD request to the server and see if that contains content-length.

Comment: @snakecharmerb no luck here. :( Got me crazy enough.

Comment: some servers send differen response for different `user-agent` or different `accept`.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Lukasa](https://github.com/Lukasa) at github:

> The response is different because requests indicates that it supports
>   gzip-encoded bodies, by sending an Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   header field. urllib2 does not. You'll find if you added that header
>   to your urllib2 request that you get the new behaviour.
>
> Clearly, in this case, the server is dynamically gzipping the
>   responses. This means it doesn't know how long the response will be,
>   so it is sending using chunked transfer encoding.
>
> If you really must get the Content-Length header, then you should add
>   the following headers to your Requests request: {'Accept-Encoding':
>   'identity'}.